# When move constructor are called

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I would like to know when move constructor are called in C++ code.

It means, I know that when I call `Foo a(b)` it is copy constructor, so what have I to code to call move constructor.

Comment: The answers on [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics) will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A move constructor is just another constructor. If you have overloaded constructors, just like having any other functions overloaded, the choice of which constructor is called comes down to the rules of overload resolution. That is, when you construct an object with `Foo a(<some-expression>);`, there might be multiple possible constructors and one needs to be chosen.

The copy constructor takes one argument of type `const Foo&`. This lvalue reference type will bind to any expression denoting a `Foo` object. The move constructor takes one argument of type `Foo&&`.  This rvalue reference will only bind to modifiable rvalues. In fact, this overload will be preferred in the case of passing a modifiable rvalue.

This means that in `Foo a(<some-expression>);` if the expression `<some-expression>` is a modifiable rvalue, the move constructor will be chosen. Otherwise the copy constructor is chosen. Modifiable rvalues usually appear when denoting temporary objects (for example, an object returned from a function). It is also possible to force an expression to an rvalue expression by using `std::move`, such as `Foo a(std::move(b));`.

Comment: In your example of Foo a(b), `b` is a named object and therefore it can't be an rvalue. `std::move(b)` would be required here.

Comment: @MichaelGazonda I'm treating `b` as a general expression, not specifically the expression `b`. I'll make that clearer.

Answer (score 3):

In general we have to tell it by giving an `rvalue` reference argument. For example:

```
template<class T>
void swap(T& a, T& b)
{
  T tmp = std::move(a);
  a = std::move(b);
  b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

The `move()` is a standard-library function returning an rvalue reference to its argument 
`move(x)` means "give me an rvalue reference to x". That is, `std::move(x)` does not move anything, instead, it allows a user to move x.

Source: The C++ Programming Language (B. Stroustrup)